# Image drag causes Button drag

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I have an `ImageView` and a `Button` in a `LinearLayout`. I want to drag the `ImageView` across the screen but have the `Button` stay in place. But for some reason when I drag my `ImageView` the `Button` drags along with it.

Can someone please help?

Code:

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum=10
    android:id="@+id/main">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/my_pic"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/click"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_click"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    ImageView img;
    private ViewGroup mRrootLayout;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRrootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main);
        img = (ImageView) mRrootLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);

        img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        img.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.logo:
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                        _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                mRrootLayout.invalidate();
                break;

            case R.id.fade:
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Ha that is true. Ill change that. But do you have a solution perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

In the onTouch you should check to see which view is being touched so you know only to move that view. For example:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.image:

            //Your code goes here

            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

That way, only the view you are referencing is moved.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I edited the onTouch method above but it gives me the same error. I guess the problem is the ACTION_MOVE. Perhaps I redraw the entire screen everytime the image is moved so it moves the button too. Can you tell me how to change it so only the image moves and not the button? I've been stuck on this for a while...